find the hidden message. Users of Dinosaurs, no pterodactyls
Find the hidden message in the below text.

find the hidden message.
Users of Dinosaurs,
no pterodactyls.
People that disagree,
everyone agrees.
Oatmeal is good for
Paul.
Like,
everyone.
Are you
really
eying a camera?
Cameras are made by
Olympus, Phase
One, and
Leica.


Fun people are cool.
... is the sentence formed by the first letter in each row.

should I make the harder? this was answered before I can even accept an answer.

@Twineee I'd say this is very easy by the site's standards, yes. You could absolutely make it harder.
